# Performance testing with Load balance, Is that be suitable?

Tags: testing, performance

I'm trying to do a performance testing with my application under a load balancer.

That makes me curious If we test an application under load balancer Is that mean we are testing load balancer or our application?

Since our load testing request will send to load balancer first not application.

Could you help me clarify this things?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are testing both.

Load balancer is a special type of application which directly depends on the "actual" application processing user's request, ie. a state of the application server affects the routing of the load balancer.

Testing your application by accessing it using the load balancer verifies your application can handle expected load as well as the correctness of the balancing strategy.